# Flutter MaterialApp - How can I use the AppBar title as a link

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I want to turn the title of the AppBar of a the default Flutter app created by the New Project template into a link. Here is my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
    title: 'WaterFlow Target',
    theme: new ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: new MyHomePage(title: 'WaterFlow'),
  );
}
}
```

In the 9th line you can see the MyHomePage constructor call with the title parameter.

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by **use it as a link**? do you want the appBar clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Add `url_launcher` plugin to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher: 2.0.1
```

Write this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class TitleLink extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          elevation: 0.5,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: new InkWell(
            child: new Text("www.google.com"),
            onTap: () => launch('https://google.com'),
          ),
        ),
        body: new Center(child: new Text("Tap on Title to open Google"))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When using url_launcher with Flutter, make sure your Flutter project's Gradle build setup is compatible with the Flutter project version. If you get any Gradle error reports, switch to version 1.0.2 of the url_launcher package. See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher/versions/2.0.0#-changelog-tab- for details.